# Yii CStarRating does not show half filled star for decimal value

Tags: yii, rating

This is my code written in Cgridview in yii.

```
 array(
         'header'=>'Avg Rating',
         'type' => 'raw',
         'value'=>'$this->grid->controller->widget(\'CStarRating\',
                                            array(
                                                    \'name\'=>$data->rating.$data->id,
                                                    \'id\'=>$data->id,
                                                    \'readOnly\' => true,
                                                    \'value\' =>2.5,
                                                     \'minRating\'=>1,
                                                     \'maxRating\'=>5,
                                                     \'htmlOptions\'=>array(\'style\'=>\'text-align:center;\',)),true)." <br/>1,011 Reviews"',
         'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;'),
    ),
```

when i pass integer,it shows me proper filled star,but when i pass values like 2.5 ,it shows all star blank.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this this way:

```
array(
     'header'=>'Avg Rating',
     'type' => 'raw',
     'value'=>'$this->grid->controller->widget(\'CStarRating\',
                                        array(
                                                \'name\'=>$data->rating.$data->id,
                                                \'id\'=>$data->id,
                                                \'readOnly\' => true,
                                                \'value\' =>2.5,
                                                 \'minRating\'=>0.5,
                                                 \'maxRating\'=>5,
                                                 \'ratingStepSize\' => 0.5,
                                                 \'htmlOptions\'=>array(\'style\'=>\'text-align:center;\',)),true)." <br/>1,011 Reviews"',
     'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;'),
),
```

or can try other values for `minRating` and `ratingStepSize`.